# SQL query with an order by clause on two columns, both descending

Tags: sql-server, sql-order-by

I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT [columns] 
FROM [Leads]
ORDER BY Leads.scanDate DESC, Leads.lastName, Leads.LeadID DESC
```

It is my understanding that first the data will be sorted by scanDate with the newest scans coming first, and then the data will be sorted by last name and lead id, so could the ORDER BY clause not just be

```
ORDER BY scandate, lastName, LeadID DESC
```

Secondly, I tried to diagnose the issue with this code

```
DECLARE @tmptable table
(
    scandate datetime,
    lastname varchar(20),
    leadid int
);
INSERT INTO @tmptable VALUES ('2016-05-10 10:21:30', 'bar', 21);
INSERT INTO @tmptable VALUES ('2016-05-10 10:21:30', 'foo', 21);

SELECT * 
FROM @tmptable 
ORDER BY leadid, lastname desc
```

The result is the foo row is first and bar row is second, but when I add the scandate column to the order, the bar row is first.

In short, isn't the 2 DESC clauses redundant, one would suffice?

Comment: No, you need both `DESC`, because without it, you're saying `ORDER BY ScanDate ASC, LastName ASC, LeadID DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you don't put a "DESC" in the order by clause, the logic applicable would be that it the default sort would be "ASC". Therefore, you must put a DESC after each field (But not required for ASC).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare the type of sorting in a column, SQL will sort of way "ASC" by default, All the columns you want to sort of way "DESC" you will need to put "DESC" after the column